# How to create a jabber/XMPP proxy/logging service?

Tags: java, xml-rpc, xmpp, smack

I am working for a company that is using Google Chatback (anonymous chat with a support employee in my company's case) as the main chat service provider. This service uses the XMPP (formerly known as Jabber) protocol for sending and receiving messages.

Our company has ten support employee accounts, and they are accessible through the chatback service we have used on our website. The employees use both Mac OSX and Windows, along with different clients on the different OSes. The chat is also available through native apps on both Android and iOS.

We need a service for logging the chat sessions, and we have been looking into proprietary solutions, but these are not supported on the mobile platforms, and that's basically the dealbreaker.

The solution I have decided is to introduce another link in the message chain, that logs all messages. The idea is that the server sends through this proxy, that logs the messages according to which chat session it is, and then saves those logs in an appropriate manner. Currently they are storing all the logs in a Dropbox folder, which is an error-prone activity.

This would, in theory, allow our supporters to use whatever os/client they chose, and the logs would end up the same place.

Having conducted some tests using the Smack API, I have concluded that my XMPP client (Trillian on both Android and Windows) replies to the resource from which it last received a message. This means effectively that the very simple chat logger I have implemented simply gets ignored.

The test have been conducted using the code below coupled with another client that runs in parallel. Only one of the clients receives the message.

```
ConnectionConfiguration config = new ConnectionConfiguration("talk.google.com", 5222, "googlemail.com");
config.setSecurityMode(ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.required);
config.setSASLAuthenticationEnabled(true);
XMPPConnection connection = new XMPPConnection(config);
connection.connect();

Presence presence = new Presence(Presence.Type.unavailable);
connection.login("android_client_username", "android_client_pass");
Message message = new Message("my_test_email@gmail.com");
message.setBody("Hello World!");
connection.sendPacket(message);
connection.sendPacket(presence);
connection.addPacketListener(new PacketListener() {
          public void processPacket(Packet packet) {
             if (packet instanceof Message) {
                Message message = (Message) packet;
                System.out.println(message.getBody()); 
             }
           }
        }, new MessageTypeFilter(Message.Type.chat));
```

- Is it possible to create such a proxy using the Google Talk service i.e. without hosting our own XMPP server?
- Is it at all possible to listen in on all packets on the server remotely?
- If not, what alternatives are there for anonymous web-based chat clients that utilize an open protocol such as XMPP?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you DON'T USE the Google Chatback service it is relatively easy to set up the environment you need. In order to log XMPP messages, the chat must be done via MUC (multi-user-chat). You need the following components:

- Book: http://professionalxmpp.com/
- HTTP server
- Jabber/XMPP server (e.g. ejabberd)
- Chat-room per support seat
- Use perl and Net::Jabber (not Net::XMPP since it does not support MUC) to create script/process/daemon which will login to the XMPP server and join the appropriate chat-room. Other participants in the chat-room would be one of your support guys, and the guy asking for support. The script must be set in such a way that it makes whatever you want upon the receipt of MUC message (e.g. store in database). Not so much of a job since when you install Net::Jabber, there are example scripts in which you need to add/modify only part of the code.
- If you want to chat via web browser, Strophe.js must be used in order to establish BOSH connection with the XMPP server, via HTTP server by proper proxy configuration.

All this stuff can be found in the book, except for Perl script using Net::Jabber.

I was maybe not much of a help but if you decide to go this way, I'll help. If Google Chatback supports MUC, then all you need is Perl/Net::Jabber part.

EDIT: the perl XMPP daemon

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use Net::Jabber;
use threads;
use DBI;

my $server = shift @ARGV;
my $port = shift @ARGV;
my $username = shift @ARGV;
my $password = shift @ARGV;
my $resource = shift @ARGV;
my $chatroom = shift @ARGV;

my %img = ('URGENT' => 'urgent.png',
            'HIGH' => 'high.png',
            'MEDIUM' => 'medium.png',
            'LOW' => 'low.png');

my $dbname_status= 'db';
my $dbuser_status= 'user';
my $dbpass_status= 'pass';
my $dbhost_status = 'localhost';
my $dbport_status = 5432;

my $dbh_status = DBI->connect("dbi:Pg:dbname=$dbname_status;host=$dbhost_status;port=$dbport_status", $dbuser_status, $dbpass_status, {AutoCommit => 0, RaiseError => 1});
my $sth_status = $dbh_status->prepare(qq{SELECT * FROM sosrhs_ticketstatus});
$sth_status->execute;
my %status = ();
while (my $res = $sth_status->fetchrow_hashref)
{
    $status{$res->{status}} = $res->{id};
}
$sth_status->finish;
$dbh_status->disconnect;

print "\nSERVER: ", $server, "\n";
print 'PORT: ', $port, "\n";
print 'USERNAME: ', $username, "\n";
print 'RESOURCE: ', $resource, "\n";


$SIG{HUP} = \&Stop;
$SIG{KILL} = \&Stop;
$SIG{TERM} = \&Stop;
$SIG{INT} = \&Stop;

my $Connection = new Net::Jabber::Client();

$Connection->SetCallBacks(message => sub {threads->create('InMessage', (@_))->join()},
                          presence => sub {threads->create('InPresence', (@_))->join()},
                          iq => sub {threads->create('InIQ', (@_))->join()}
                          );

my $status = $Connection->Connect(hostname=>$server,
                                  port=>$port,
                                 );

if (!(defined($status)))
{
    print "ERROR:  Jabber server is down or connection was not allowed.\n";
    print "        ($!)\n";
    exit(0);
}

my @result = $Connection->AuthSend(username=>$username,
                                   password=>$password,
                                   resource=>$resource);

if ($result[0] ne "ok")
{
    print "ERROR: Authorization failed: $result[0] - $result[1]\n";
    exit(0);
}

print "Logged in to $server:$port...\n";

$Connection->RosterGet();

print "Getting Roster to tell server to send presence info...\n";

$Connection->PresenceSend();

print "Sending presence to tell world that we are logged in...\n";

$Connection->MUCJoin(room => $chatroom,
                    server => 'conference.' . $server,
                    nick => $username);

print 'Join ' . $chatroom . '@conference.sosrhs MUC room...';
print "\n";

while(defined($Connection->Process())) { }

print "ERROR: The connection was killed...\n";

exit(0);


sub Stop
{
    print "Exiting...\n";
    $Connection->Disconnect();
    exit(0);
}


sub InMessage
{
    my $sid = shift;
    my $message = shift;

    my $type = $message->GetType();
    my $fromJID = $message->GetFrom("jid");

    my $from = $fromJID->GetUserID();
    my $resource = $fromJID->GetResource();
    my $subject = $message->GetSubject();
    my $body = $message->GetBody();
    #print "===\n";
    #print "Message ($type)\n";
    #print "  From: $from ($resource)\n";
    #print "  Subject: $subject\n";
    #print "  Body: $body\n";
    #print "===\n";
    #print $message->GetXML(),"\n";
    #print "===\n";

    if ($from eq 'ticket_distributor')
    {
        if ($body =~ /^ticketrelay /)
        {
            &to_group($body);
        }
        elsif ($body =~ /^ackrelay /)
        {
            &to_group_ack($body);
        }
        elsif ($body =~ /^ticketupdaterelay /)
        {
            &to_group_update($body);
        }
        elsif ($body =~ /^ticketwithdrawrelay /)
        {
            &to_group_withdraw($body);
        }
        elsif ($body =~ /^ticketclearrelay /)
        {
            &to_group_clear($body);
        }
        elsif ($body =~ /^ticketcloserelay /)
        {
            &to_group_close($body);
        }
        elsif ($body =~ /^ticketfwdrelay /)
        {
            &to_group_fwd($body);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if ($body =~ /^ticketnew /)
        {
            &to_group($body);
            &to_ticket_distributor($body);
        }
        elsif ($body =~ /^ack /)
        {
            &to_ticket_distributor_ack($body);
        }
        elsif ($body =~ /^ticketupdate /)
        {
            &to_ticket_distributor_update($body);
        }
        elsif ($body =~ /^ticketwithdraw /)
        {
            &to_ticket_distributor_withdraw($body);
        }
        elsif ($body =~ /^ticketclear /)
        {
            &to_ticket_distributor_clear($body);
        }
        elsif ($body =~ /^ticketclose /)
        {
            &to_ticket_distributor_close($body);
        }
        elsif ($body =~ /^ticketfwd /)
        {
            &to_ticket_distributor_fwd($body);
        }
    }
}


sub InIQ
{
    my $sid = shift;
    my $iq = shift;

    my $from = $iq->GetFrom();
    my $type = $iq->GetType();
    my $query = $iq->GetQuery();
    my $xmlns = $query->GetXMLNS();
    #print "===\n";
    #print "IQ\n";
    #print "  From $from\n";
    #print "  Type: $type\n";
    #print "  XMLNS: $xmlns";
    #print "===\n";
    #print $iq->GetXML(),"\n";
    #print "===\n";
}

sub InPresence
{
    my $sid = shift;
    my $presence = shift;

    my $from = $presence->GetFrom();
    my $type = $presence->GetType();
    my $status = $presence->GetStatus();
    #print "===\n";
    #print "Presence\n";
    #print "  From $from\n";
    #print "  Type: $type\n";
    #print "  Status: $status\n";
    #print "===\n";
    #print $presence->GetXML(),"\n";
    #print "===\n";

    if ($type eq 'subscribe')
    {
        my @usrreq = split('@', $from);
        my $usrreq = $usrreq[0] . '@' . $server;
        $Connection->Subscription(type => 'subscribed',
                                    to => $usrreq
                                    );
    }
}

# Functions for actions taken upon ticket
sub to_ticket_distributor
{
    my $msg = shift;
    my @msg = split(' ', $msg);
    print "\n$username : $msg[0] $msg[1]\n";
    my $dbname= 'db';
    my $dbuser= 'user';
    my $dbpass= 'pass';
    my $dbhost = 'localhost';
    my $dbport = 5432;

    my $dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:Pg:dbname=$dbname;host=$dbhost;port=$dbport", $dbuser, $dbpass, {AutoCommit => 0, RaiseError => 1});
    my $sth = $dbh->prepare(qq{SELECT * FROM sosrhs_tickets_v where ticket_id = ?});
    $sth->execute($msg[1]);
    my $group_assigned_groupnamechat = '';
    while (my $res = $sth->fetchrow_hashref)
    {
        $group_assigned_groupnamechat = $res->{group_assigned_groupnamechat};
    }
    $sth->finish;

    $dbh->disconnect;

    $Connection->MessageSend(to => 'ticket_distributor@' . $server,
                            type => 'chat',
                            body => $msg[1] . ' ' . $group_assigned_groupnamechat);
}

sub to_ticket_distributor_ack
{
    my $msg = shift;
    my @msg = split(' ', $msg);
    print "\n$username : $msg[0] $msg[1] $msg[2]\n";
    my $dbname= 'db';
    my $dbuser= 'user';
    my $dbpass= 'pass';
    my $dbhost = 'localhost';
    my $dbport = 5432;

    my $dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:Pg:dbname=$dbname;host=$dbhost;port=$dbport", $dbuser, $dbpass, {AutoCommit => 0, RaiseError => 1});
    my $sth = $dbh->do(qq{UPDATE sosrhs_tickets SET ticketstatus = $status{'WORK IN PROGRESS'}, user_accepted = '$msg[2]', tmstmp_accepted = now() WHERE ticket_id = $msg[1]});
    $dbh->commit;

    $sth = $dbh->prepare(qq{SELECT * FROM sosrhs_tickets_v where ticket_id = ?});
    $sth->execute($msg[1]);
    my $user_creator_groups_id = '';
    while (my $res = $sth->fetchrow_hashref)
    {
        $user_creator_groups_id = $res->{user_creator_groups_id};
    }
    $sth->finish;

    $sth = $dbh->prepare(qq{SELECT groupnamechat FROM sosrhs_groups WHERE id = ?});
    $sth->execute($user_creator_groups_id);
    my $user_creator_groupchatname = '';
    while (my $res = $sth->fetchrow_hashref)
    {
        $user_creator_groupchatname = $res->{groupnamechat};
    }
    $sth->finish;

    $dbh->disconnect;

    $Connection->MessageSend(to => 'ticket_distributor@' . $server,
                            type => 'chat',
                            body => 'ackrelay ' . $msg[1] . ' ' . $user_creator_groupchatname);

    $Connection->MessageSend(to => $chatroom . '@conference.' . $server,
                            type => 'groupchat',
                            body => 'ackfinish ' . $msg[1]);
}

sub to_ticket_distributor_update
{
    my $msg = shift;
    my @msg = split(' ', $msg);
    print "\n$username : $msg[0] $msg[1] $msg[2]\n";
    my $ticket_action = shift @msg;
    my $ticket_id = shift @msg;
    my $user_id_update = shift @msg;
    my $ticket_comment = join(' ', @msg);
    my $dbname= 'db';
    my $dbuser= 'user';
    my $dbpass= 'pass';
    my $dbhost = 'localhost';
    my $dbport = 5432;

    my $dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:Pg:dbname=$dbname;host=$dbhost;port=$dbport", $dbuser, $dbpass, {AutoCommit => 0, RaiseError => 1});
    my $sth = $dbh->prepare(qq{INSERT INTO sosrhs_tickets_comments (ticket_id, users_id, comment) VALUES (?, ?, ?)});
    $sth->execute($ticket_id, $user_id_update, $ticket_comment);
    $dbh->commit;

    $sth = $dbh->prepare(qq{SELECT * FROM sosrhs_tickets_v where ticket_id = ?});
    $sth->execute($ticket_id);
    my $user_creator_groups_id = '';
    while (my $res = $sth->fetchrow_hashref)
    {
        $user_creator_groups_id = $res->{user_creator_groups_id};
    }
    $sth->finish;

    $sth = $dbh->prepare(qq{SELECT groupnamechat FROM sosrhs_groups WHERE id = ?});
    $sth->execute($user_creator_groups_id);
    my $user_creator_groupchatname = '';
    while (my $res = $sth->fetchrow_hashref)
    {
        $user_creator_groupchatname = $res->{groupnamechat};
    }
    $sth->finish;

    $dbh->disconnect;

    $Connection->MessageSend(to => 'ticket_distributor@' . $server,
                            type => 'chat',
                            body => 'ticketupdaterelay ' . $ticket_id . ' ' . $user_creator_groupchatname);

    $Connection->MessageSend(to => $chatroom . '@conference.' . $server,
                            type => 'groupchat',
                            body => 'ticketupdatefinish ' . $ticket_id);
}

sub to_ticket_distributor_withdraw
{
    my $msg = shift;
    my @msg = split(' ', $msg);
    print "\n$username : $msg[0] $msg[1]\n";
    my $ticket_action = shift @msg;
    my $ticket_id = shift @msg;
    my $user_id_withdraw = shift @msg;
    my $dbname= 'db';
    my $dbuser= 'user';
    my $dbpass= 'pass';
    my $dbhost = 'localhost';
    my $dbport = 5432;

    my $dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:Pg:dbname=$dbname;host=$dbhost;port=$dbport", $dbuser, $dbpass, {AutoCommit => 0, RaiseError => 1});
    my $sth = $dbh->do(qq{UPDATE sosrhs_tickets SET ticketstatus = $status{'WITHDRAWN'}, user_withdrawn = $user_id_withdraw, tmstmp_withdrawn = now() WHERE ticket_id = $ticket_id});
    $dbh->commit;

    $sth = $dbh->prepare(qq{SELECT * FROM sosrhs_tickets_v where ticket_id = ?});
    $sth->execute($ticket_id);
    my $user_creator_groups_id = '';
    while (my $res = $sth->fetchrow_hashref)
    {
        $user_creator_groups_id = $res->{user_creator_groups_id};
    }
    $sth->finish;

    $sth = $dbh->prepare(qq{SELECT groupnamechat FROM sosrhs_groups WHERE id = ?});
    $sth->execute($user_creator_groups_id);
    my $user_creator_groupchatname = '';
    while (my $res = $sth->fetchrow_hashref)
    {
        $user_creator_groupchatname = $res->{groupnamechat};
    }
    $sth->finish;

    $dbh->disconnect;

    $Connection->MessageSend(to => 'ticket_distributor@' . $server,
                            type => 'chat',
                            body => 'ticketwithdrawrelay ' . $ticket_id . ' ' . $user_creator_groupchatname);

    $Connection->MessageSend(to => $chatroom . '@conference.' . $server,
                            type => 'groupchat',
                            body => 'ticketwithdrawfinish ' . $ticket_id);
}

sub to_ticket_distributor_clear
{
    my $msg = shift;
    my @msg = split(' ', $msg);
    print "\n$username : $msg[0] $msg[1]\n";
    my $ticket_action = shift @msg;
    my $ticket_id = shift @msg;
    my $user_id_clear = shift @msg;
    my $dbname= 'db';
    my $dbuser= 'user';
    my $dbpass= 'pass';
    my $dbhost = 'localhost';
    my $dbport = 5432;

    my $dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:Pg:dbname=$dbname;host=$dbhost;port=$dbport", $dbuser, $dbpass, {AutoCommit => 0, RaiseError => 1});
    my $sth = $dbh->do(qq{UPDATE sosrhs_tickets SET ticketstatus = $status{'CLEARED'}, user_cleared = $user_id_clear, tmstmp_cleared = now() WHERE ticket_id = $ticket_id});
    $dbh->commit;

    $sth = $dbh->prepare(qq{SELECT * FROM sosrhs_tickets_v where ticket_id = ?});
    $sth->execute($ticket_id);
    my $user_creator_groups_id = '';
    while (my $res = $sth->fetchrow_hashref)
    {
        $user_creator_groups_id = $res->{user_creator_groups_id};
    }
    $sth->finish;

    $sth = $dbh->prepare(qq{SELECT groupnamechat FROM sosrhs_groups WHERE id = ?});
    $sth->execute($user_creator_groups_id);
    my $user_creator_groupchatname = '';
    while (my $res = $sth->fetchrow_hashref)
    {
        $user_creator_groupchatname = $res->{groupnamechat};
    }
    $sth->finish;

    $dbh->disconnect;

    $Connection->MessageSend(to => 'ticket_distributor@' . $server,
                            type => 'chat',
                            body => 'ticketclearrelay ' . $ticket_id . ' ' . $user_creator_groupchatname);

    $Connection->MessageSend(to => $chatroom . '@conference.' . $server,
                            type => 'groupchat',
                            body => 'ticketclearfinish ' . $ticket_id);
}

sub to_ticket_distributor_close
{
    my $msg = shift;
    my @msg = split(' ', $msg);
    print "\n$username : $msg[0] $msg[1]\n";
    my $ticket_action = shift @msg;
    my $ticket_id = shift @msg;
    my $user_id_close = shift @msg;
    my $dbname= 'db';
    my $dbuser= 'user';
    my $dbpass= 'pass';
    my $dbhost = 'localhost';
    my $dbport = 5432;

    my $dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:Pg:dbname=$dbname;host=$dbhost;port=$dbport", $dbuser, $dbpass, {AutoCommit => 0, RaiseError => 1});
    my $sth = $dbh->do(qq{UPDATE sosrhs_tickets SET ticketstatus = $status{'CLOSED'}, user_closed = $user_id_close, tmstmp_closed = now() WHERE ticket_id = $ticket_id});
    $dbh->commit;

    $sth = $dbh->prepare(qq{SELECT groupnamechat FROM sosrhs_users_v WHERE groups_id = (SELECT group_assigned_id FROM sosrhs_tickets_v WHERE ticket_id = ?)});
    $sth->execute($ticket_id);
    my $user_accepted_groupchatname = '';
    while (my $res = $sth->fetchrow_hashref)
    {
        $user_accepted_groupchatname = $res->{groupnamechat};
    }
    $sth->finish;

    $dbh->disconnect;

    $Connection->MessageSend(to => 'ticket_distributor@' . $server,
                            type => 'chat',
                            body => 'ticketcloserelay ' . $ticket_id . ' ' . $user_accepted_groupchatname);

    $Connection->MessageSend(to => $chatroom . '@conference.' . $server,
                            type => 'groupchat',
                            body => 'ticketclosefinish ' . $ticket_id);
}

sub to_ticket_distributor_fwd
{
    my $msg = shift;
    my @msg = split(' ', $msg);
    print "\n$username : $msg[0] $msg[1] $msg[2]\n";
    my $ticket_action = shift @msg;
    my $ticket_id = shift @msg;
    my $user_id_fwd = shift @msg;
    my $group_id_fwd_to = shift @msg;
    my $dbname= 'db';
    my $dbuser= 'user';
    my $dbpass= 'pass';
    my $dbhost = 'localhost';
    my $dbport = 5432;

    my $dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:Pg:dbname=$dbname;host=$dbhost;port=$dbport", $dbuser, $dbpass, {AutoCommit => 0, RaiseError => 1});
    my $sth = $dbh->do(qq{UPDATE sosrhs_tickets SET ticketstatus = $status{'ASSIGNED'}, user_accepted = NULL, tmstmp_accepted = NULL, group_assigned = $group_id_fwd_to WHERE ticket_id = $ticket_id});
    $dbh->commit;

    $sth = $dbh->prepare(qq{INSERT INTO sosrhs_tickets_comments (ticket_id, users_id, groups_id_fwd_to) VALUES (?, ?, ?)});
    $sth->execute($ticket_id, $user_id_fwd, $group_id_fwd_to);
    $dbh->commit;

    $sth = $dbh->prepare(qq{SELECT groupnamechat FROM sosrhs_groups WHERE id = (SELECT group_assigned_id FROM sosrhs_tickets_v WHERE ticket_id = ?)});
    $sth->execute($ticket_id);
    my $user_fwd_groupchatname = '';
    while (my $res = $sth->fetchrow_hashref)
    {
        $user_fwd_groupchatname = $res->{groupnamechat};
    }
    $sth->finish;

    $sth = $dbh->prepare(qq{SELECT groupnamechat FROM sosrhs_groups WHERE id = (SELECT user_creator_groups_id FROM sosrhs_tickets_v WHERE ticket_id = ?)});
    $sth->execute($ticket_id);
    my $user_creator_groupchatname = '';
    while (my $res = $sth->fetchrow_hashref)
    {
        $user_creator_groupchatname = $res->{groupnamechat};
    }
    $sth->finish;

    $dbh->disconnect;

    $Connection->MessageSend(to => 'ticket_distributor@' . $server,
                            type => 'chat',
                            body => 'ticketfwdrelay ' . $ticket_id . ' ' . $user_fwd_groupchatname);

    $Connection->MessageSend(to => 'ticket_distributor@' . $server,
                            type => 'chat',
                            body => 'ticketfwdrelay ' . $ticket_id . ' ' . $user_creator_groupchatname);

    $Connection->MessageSend(to => $chatroom . '@conference.' . $server,
                            type => 'groupchat',
                            body => 'ticketfwdfinish ' . $ticket_id);
}

# Functions for relayed actions from ticket_distributor
sub to_group
{
    my $msg = shift;
    my @msg = split(' ', $msg);
    print "\n$username : $msg[0] $msg[1]\n";

    $Connection->MessageSend(to => $chatroom . '@conference.' . $server,
                            type => 'groupchat',
                            body => &build_new_ticket_message($msg[1]));
}

sub to_group_ack
{
    my $msg = shift;
    my @msg = split(' ', $msg);
    print "\n$username : $msg[0] $msg[1]\n";

    $Connection->MessageSend(to => $chatroom . '@conference.' . $server,
                            type => 'groupchat',
                            body => 'ackrelay ' . $msg[1]);
}

sub to_group_update
{
    my $msg = shift;
    my @msg = split(' ', $msg);
    print "\n$username : $msg[0] $msg[1]\n";

    $Connection->MessageSend(to => $chatroom . '@conference.' . $server,
                            type => 'groupchat',
                            body => 'ticketupdaterelay ' . $msg[1]);
}

sub to_group_withdraw
{
    my $msg = shift;
    my @msg = split(' ', $msg);
    print "\n$username : $msg[0] $msg[1]\n";

    $Connection->MessageSend(to => $chatroom . '@conference.' . $server,
                            type => 'groupchat',
                            body => 'ticketwithdrawrelay ' . $msg[1]);
}

sub to_group_clear
{
    my $msg = shift;
    my @msg = split(' ', $msg);
    print "\n$username : $msg[0] $msg[1]\n";

    $Connection->MessageSend(to => $chatroom . '@conference.' . $server,
                            type => 'groupchat',
                            body => 'ticketclearrelay ' . $msg[1]);
}

sub to_group_close
{
    my $msg = shift;
    my @msg = split(' ', $msg);
    print "\n$username : $msg[0] $msg[1]\n";

    $Connection->MessageSend(to => $chatroom . '@conference.' . $server,
                            type => 'groupchat',
                            body => 'ticketcloserelay ' . $msg[1]);
}

sub to_group_fwd
{
    my $msg = shift;
    my @msg = split(' ', $msg);
    print "\n$username : $msg[0] $msg[1]\n";

    $Connection->MessageSend(to => $chatroom . '@conference.' . $server,
                            type => 'groupchat',
                            body => 'ticketfwdrelay ' . $msg[1]);

    sleep 2;

    $Connection->MessageSend(to => $chatroom . '@conference.' . $server,
                            type => 'groupchat',
                            body => &build_new_ticket_message($msg[1]));
}

sub build_new_ticket_message
{
    my $ticket_id = shift;

    my $dbname= 'db';
    my $dbuser= 'user';
    my $dbpass= 'pass';
    my $dbhost = 'localhost';
    my $dbport = 5432;

    my $dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:Pg:dbname=$dbname;host=$dbhost;port=$dbport", $dbuser, $dbpass, {AutoCommit => 0, RaiseError => 1});
    my $sth = $dbh->prepare(qq{SELECT * FROM sosrhs_tickets_v where ticket_id = ?});
    $sth->execute($ticket_id);
    my %ticket = ();
    while (my $res = $sth->fetchrow_hashref)
    {
        $ticket{ticket_id} = $res->{ticket_id};
        $ticket{ticketcategory_category} = $res->{ticketcategory_category};
        $ticket{ticketstatus_status} = $res->{ticketstatus_status};
        $ticket{ticketpriority_severityname} = $res->{ticketpriority_severityname};
        $ticket{tmstmp_assigned} = $res->{tmstmp_assigned};
        $ticket{user_creator_firstname} = $res->{user_creator_firstname};
        $ticket{user_creator_secondname} = $res->{user_creator_secondname};
        $ticket{group_assigned_groupname} = $res->{group_assigned_groupname};
        $ticket{ticket_text} = $res->{ticket_text};
        $ticket{ticket_file} = $res->{ticket_file};
        $ticket{subject} = $res->{subject};
        $ticket{user_creator_groups_id} = $res->{user_creator_groups_id};
    }
    $sth->finish;

    $dbh->disconnect;

    my $html_msg = q!<p id="p! . $ticket{ticket_id} . q!">
                        <img src="/sosrhs/images/! . $img{$ticket{ticketpriority_severityname}} . q!"/>&nbsp;<text id="t! . $ticket{ticket_id} . q!" class="textmainleft">! . substr($ticket{tmstmp_assigned}, 0, 16) . '&nbsp;|&nbsp;' . $ticket{ticketstatus_status} . '&nbsp;|&nbsp;' . $ticket{ticketcategory_category} . '&nbsp;|&nbsp;' . $ticket{subject} . '<br>From:&nbsp;' . $ticket{user_creator_firstname} . '&nbsp;' . $ticket{user_creator_secondname} . '&nbsp;|&nbsp;To:&nbsp;' . $ticket{group_assigned_groupname} . q!</text>&nbsp;|&nbsp;<a href="#" onClick="$('#explanation').fadeOut('fast'); $('div.divmainleft > p').css('background-color', 'white'); $('#p! . $ticket{ticket_id} . q!').css('background-color', '#E0E0F8'); $('#tdexplanation').load('/cgi-bin/sosrhs/ticket_details.pl?ticket_id=! . $ticket{ticket_id} . q!&my_groupchatname=! . $chatroom . q!');">Details</a>
                    </p>!;

                    #<hr id="h! . $ticket{ticket_id} . q!" style="height: 1px; border-width: 0; color: gray; background-color: gray;"/>!;

    return $html_msg;
}
```

Comment: The cost of this setup is much less than me developing some extensive logging daemon that acts as a man-in-the-middle. Thank you very much for the answer!

Comment: The question "Does Google Chatback" support MUC?" remains to be answered. Maybe then everything will be less complicated.

Comment: I don't think they do, but hosting our own server will have to do.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use XMPP over HTTP, then log the messages using an HTTP proxy (set all your XMPP clients to talk to the HTTP proxy rather than the endpoint directly)?

Comment: I hadn't thought of that, great idea! Will the data readable by the proxy despite the built-in encryption of google talk?

Comment: Hmm, I guess not :-( unless you want to MITM the HTTPS with a spoofed cert, unlikely to be a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

I am not too sure if it will affect you and your service, but just for your information in past i have experienced 407 Proxy Auth. response code while trying to make cross domain text/xml ajax requests. Mostly if you are behind a firewall/http-proxy(squid) kind of environment. Solution to that is mostly fallback mode to jsonp when behind a proxy.

Test Verify:
1) setup local squid
2) use strophejs basic examples
3) setup cross domain ajax i.e. BOSH_SERVICE_URL domain is not same as requestor domain
4) configure browser to use local squid
5) You will find all POST api calls i.e. /http-bind text/xml calls will fail with 407 proxy auth response code
6) remove proxy-usage from browser
7) try again, everything works with CORS enabled

Answer (score 0):

you can try gozerbot if you manage to configure it